# Python regex bool test over a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, loops

I want to check if some argument in a list matches a certain pattern (two upper case letters followed by an integer: XX999999). I use a (python) regex which works fine. However, if I iterate over a list, the pattern is not correctly identified.

Probably the test fails because I call the list argument explicitly as a string `str(string)`? However, if I do not explicitly call the list argument as a string, I get an error message (TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object).

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import re

# Is true
print(bool(re.match("^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", "XZ291053")))

# Is false
print(bool(re.match("^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", "ye291053")))

# Does not work
string = ['XZ291053','ye291053','AU291049','GI291053']
for s in string:
    print(bool(re.match("^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", str(string))))
```

Comment: `[re.match(r"^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", i) for i in string]`

Comment: `print(bool(re.match("^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", s)))` ?

Comment: `string` is a list. You need to apply the regex to `s`, the current string inside the list.

Comment: Thx Wiktor, now I see it... Time for me to call it a day, I guess :-)

Comment: You shouldn't name variables `string`, it overrides a Python builtin module

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to do this, applying the regex to every string in the list:

```
[re.match(r"^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", i) for i in string]
```

To be consistent with your original post:

```
[bool(re.match(r"^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)+$", i)) for i in string]
```

This gives:

```
[True, False, True, True]
```

Also, a slight modification to your regex to match your description of the pattern you want:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]+
```